# How can i open same link 10 time in 10 tab by just clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html

How can I open the same link 10 times in 10 tabs by just clicking on button?

Is php required to do this and if so can you provide a code sample?

Below is an example of my code:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script language="javascript">
            function kishan()
            {
                window.open('http://stackoverflow.com','_blank');
           }
        </script>
        <input type="button" value="ok" onclick="kishan()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: PHP is a [server side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) scripting language, not to be confused with a client side scripting language such as [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

Just add multiple window.open to your code, or loop through it 10 times

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function add a loop as follows:

```
function kishan()
{
 for(i=0; i<10; i++){
     window.open('http://stackoverflow.com','_blank');
  }
 }
```

Make sure this is not a spam though!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way,

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script language="javascript">
    function open_10_tab() {

      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        window.open('http://stackoverflow.com', '_blank');
      }
    }
  </script>
  <form>
    <input type=button value="Open Windows" onclick="open_10_tab()">
  </form>
</body>

</html>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Find my answer.
just create a function that calls open()
and call that function multiple time in loop or any where you want.
just allow browser to not block pop-up ads.

```
 <html>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
    function kishan(){

       for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
      open()
          }

    }
        function open() {
           window.open('http://stackoverflow.com','_blank');
        }
</script>
<input type="button" value="ok" onclick="kishan()">
</body>
</html>
```